# The integral $\int_A f$ exists $\iff$ the series $\sum_i \int_A \phi_i|f|$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

**The theorem 16.5** in Munkres' analysis on manifolds reads:

Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$; let $f : A → ℝ$ be continuous. Let $\{ϕ_i\}$
be a partition of unity on $A$ having compact supports. The integral $∫_A f$ exists
if and only if the series $\sum_i \int_A \phi_i|f|$ converges and in this case $∫_A f=\sum_i \int_A \phi_if.$

**The theorem 16.3 reads:**

Let $\mathscr A$ be a collection of open sets in $ℝ^n$; let $A$ be their union. There exists a sequence $ϕ_1, ϕ_2,… $of continuous functions $ϕ_i : ℝ^n → ℝ$ such that:

(1) $ϕ_i(x) ≥ 0$ for all $x$.

(2) The set $S_i = \text{Support } ϕ_i$ is contained in $A$.

(3) Each point of $A$ has a neighborhood that intersects only finitely
many of the sets $S_i$.

(4) $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \phi_i(x)=1 $ for each x ∈ A.

(5) The functions $ϕ_i$ are of class $C^∞$.

(6) The sets $S_i$ are compact.

(7) For each $i$, the set $S_i$ is contained in an element of $A$.

A collection of functions $\{ϕ_i\}$ satisfying conditions $(1)-(4)$ is called a
partition of unity on $A$. If it satisfies (5), it is said to be of class $C^∞$; if it
satisfies (6), it is said to have compact supports; if it satisfies (7), it said to
be dominated by the collection $\mathscr A$.

I don't understand the following highlighted part in the proof of theorem 16.5. Suppose that $f$ is non negative on $A$ and that the series $\sum_i \int_A \phi_i|f|$ converges. Let $D$ be a compact rectifiable subset of $A$. **There exists an $M$ such that for all $i > M$, the function $ϕ_i$ vanishes identically on $D$ for $x ∈ D$.**

My question is: Why is the highlighted part in the last para true?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is it true for every such $f$ and every such $D$ ? please make the question clear. Thanks man.

Comment: @Balajisb: Yes for every such f and D. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By property (3) of Theorem 16.3, for each $x \in A$ there is an open set $G_x$ containing $x$ such that $\phi_i$ vanishes on $G_x$ for all but finitely many $i$. That is, there exists $N_x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $z \in G_x$ we have $\phi_i(z) = 0$ for all $i > N_x$.

Since $D \subset \bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ and $D$ is compact, there are a finite number of points $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$ such that $D \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^nG_{x_j}$. It follows that for each $z \in D$ we have $\phi_i(z) = 0$ for all $i > M = \max(N_{x_1},\ldots,N_{x_n})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-). I understand it now. I have one confusion though: in theorem 16.3, partition of unity is defined for $\scr A$ (a collection of open sets whose union $A$) but in the proof the partitions seem to be defined for A (the given open set). Here is how I interpret it- For every a in A, there is an open ball $B(a, r_a)$ contained in A so $A=\cup_{a\in A} B(a,r_a)$. So here $\scr A$ can be considered as the collection $\{B(a,r_a): a\in A\}$. Is my understanding correct? Thanks again .

Comment: @Koro: You're welcome.  I think your reasoning is correct.  On the other hand, it is not even clear why there needs to be a reference to the collection $\mathcal{A}$.  It is not mentioned again in the assertions (1) to (6).  SInce $A$ is an open set we could simply take $\mathcal{A} = \{A\}$ as a collection of open sets whose union is $A$.